# SharePoint Designer - approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

The workflow works and sends the email if approved but if denied, the email is not getting generated and does not change the workflow status.

InfoPath form has the following values for [Approval Status] (TRUE/FALSE)
[image]

Edit:
I modified the workflow to log the managers response and tested that it is being logged as "Not Approved" but email is still not being generated if status = no.
[image]

I also tested logging the managers response within the IF statement:
If YES = it logs approved.
If No = it doesn't log anything, send email or change workflow status

Comment: it kinda looks like the else statement is inside of the if?

Comment: Have you added workflow logging to validate if the logic loop is triggering the Else block and the email is failing to send, or if it's being skipped entirely? When the approval is denied does the workflow even progress out of your Parallel block?

Comment: I'll try workflow logging for further testing.  Thanks.

Comment: I edited the workflow (see image above). Still no email.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing the column from boolean to text box control (RequestStatus) and modifying the workflow as follows:
[image]